# Drawing outside a view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, ime

I am developing a soft keyboard IME for android, and I need the ability to overlay something on top of the text that is being inputted.

The android IME API basically asks for a View to be returned, and I can't seem to draw outside this view.

I have seen this on a demo on another IME (I think it was swype?) where a popup on top of the text for the possible words were shown, but I've not been able to replicate this on my Swype/Swiftkey copy.